# I want to add indexes in cosmodb

Tags: azure, indexing, containers, azure-cosmosdb

I want to add indexes in the containers.

So the first thing that I did was to put this code in the bicep and I run:

```
resource AzureCosmosDatabasesContainers 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2022-05-15' = [for (azureCosmos, index) in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[environmentCode]: {
  name: '${azureCosmos.account}/${azureCosmos.database}/${azureCosmos.name}'
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: azureCosmos.name
      indexingPolicy: {
        indexingMode: 'consistent'
        automatic: true
        includedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/*'
            indexes: [
                      {
                      kind: 'Range'
                      dataType: 'Number'
                      precision: -1
                      }
                      {
                      kind: 'Range'
                      dataType: 'String'
                      precision: -1
                      }
                    ]
          }
        ]
      }
       partitionKey: {
        paths: [
          '/_partitionKey'
        ]
        kind: 'Hash'
        version: 2
      }
      conflictResolutionPolicy: {
        mode: 'LastWriterWins'
        conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
      }
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    AzureCosmosDatabases
  ]
}]
```

But what happens was that the indexes don't appear.
[image]

The second thing that I did was to go to the Azure portal - Opened a cosmodb - Opened the Data Explorer pane - select the container that I want to add indexes - Added this code :

```
"indexes": [
   {
   "kind": "Range",
   "dataType": "Number",
    "precision": -1
   },
   {
   "kind": "Range",
   "dataType": "String",
   "precision": -1
    }
]
```

[image]

And finally, saved.
[image]

What happens is that I save and it's ok but when I open it again the configuration disappears.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please only include properly-formatted text, not images of text. For many reasons why, read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

If you are wondering about not able to see `kind`, `dataType` and `precision` attributes in your indexing policy after it is saved, then it is expected behavior.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cpythonv3#indexing-policy-examples):

> This indexing policy is equivalent to the one below which manually
> sets kind, dataType, and precision to their default values. These
> properties are no longer necessary to explicitly set and you should
> omit them from your indexing policy entirely (as shown in above
> example). **If you try to set these properties, they'll be automatically
> removed from your indexing policy**.